# Como saber Tamanho da List? ANDROID KOTLIN

Tags: android, lista, kotlin

ANDROID KOTLIN :
Seguinte: tenho meu Data Class com suas variáveis,faço uma chamada para a api e recebo no meu Adapter o tamanho da lista para add aos meus atributos no xml ok..
queria que na activity eu colocase a quantidade de itens que recebi da api
por exemplo: se existem 3 itens criados no layout mostrar: existem 3 tarefas pensentes e etc...

```
insira o código aqui
```

class MovimentacaoAdapter2 : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovimentacaoAdapter2.MovimentacaoVh2>() {

```
val mRetornaItens: MutableList<RetornaItensModel2> = mutableListOf()


inner class MovimentacaoVh2(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(retornaItensModel2: RetornaItensModel2) {
        itemView.txt_api_numeroserie.text = retornaItensModel2.numeroSerie
        itemView.txt_api_endereço.text = retornaItensModel2.enderecoVisual
        itemView.txt_api_data.text = formatDate(retornaItensModel2.dataInclusao)
    }
}

fun formatDate(date: String): String {
    val dateTime =
        LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy - HH:mm")
    val formatted = dateTime.format(formatter)
    return formatted.toString()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovimentacaoVh2 {
    val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_retorna_itens_mov2, parent, false)
    return MovimentacaoVh2(inflate)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovimentacaoVh2, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(mRetornaItens[position])
}

override fun getItemCount() = mRetornaItens.size


fun Update(it: List<RetornaItensModel2>) {
    mRetornaItens.addAll(it)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun remove(position: Int) {
    mRetornaItens.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Na minha activity queria fazer seguinte:
val SizeLits.text = "Total de tarefas pensentes : ${ ......}"

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente puxar a lista do seu Adapter.

Ex.:

```
val totalDeTarefasPendentes = adapter.mRetornaItens.size()
```

É assim que eu faço em situações que preciso da lista do adapter. Espero ter ajudado, até mais.

Comment: Vou tentar muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Tentei mas retorna sempre 0,não estou entendendo...ela infla meus cardView por exemplo tenho 3 cardView,queria mostrar existem 3 tarefas e assim por diante...

Comment: Se ela está retornando 0, deve ser porque você não inicializou o adapter com a lista de tarefas antes de chamar a lista para mostrar no TextView. Certifica de que a lista está realmente preenchida com os itens.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: opa,sim peguei direto do body ai mandei pra activity

Comment: Boa, marca sua questão como resolvida. Sucesso pra você!